# How to convert Select Statement into JSON/GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a console Java application which reads the select statement from a file using BufferedReader and then pass it to a thread for execution.

I want to make some improvements to this program, so I thought to make use of JSON or GSON to read the file and then pass this it to execution.

Any thoughts, is this a better approach?

Comment: What will JSON improve?

Comment: What do you seek to improve that could be addressed by using JSON/GSON?

Comment: You could convert your statement to syntax tree and encode that tree as Json. But why?

Comment: This Program runs for every 5 minutes, so in each run, it has to read the data from a file and then pass it to a thread. So my assumption is we can reduce the read delay if we can make use of JSON objects to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, there is a chance that converting your data file to use json encoding will cause lower performance than a buffered file reader.

Depending on your implementation, the BufferedReader only has to process each line at a time, where-as the GSON parser would have to ingest the entire file at once.  For very large files, the buffered reader will perform better overall.

Now, if your files are small enough that the previous comment isn't a concern, a JSON encoding would allow you to better encapsulate additional data with the SQL statements that you are writing.  i.e. you could attach a comment and a timestamp to each statement.